# offsetHeight for `document.documentElement` acts differently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am aware about the concept of `offsetHeight` giving me the CSS Height of the element including the borders and padding and the scroll bar width/height if present and works perfectly when I have and element in my html i.e

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>  
    #content {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
      There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
  </div>
</body>
<script>

const $div = document.getElementById('content');

console.log("CLIENT HEIGHT ", $div.clientHeight);
console.log("SCROLL HEIGHT ", $div.scrollHeight);
console.log("OFFSET HEIGHT ", $div.offsetHeight);

</script>
</html>
```

OUTPUT :

```
"CLIENT HEIGHT "
100
"SCROLL HEIGHT "
234
"OFFSET HEIGHT "
104
```

But, when I open my browser console and do the same for `document.documentElement` I get this :

[image]

You can see `offsetHeight` is including the content as well and is similar to the `scrollHeight` somehow! I am confused if you please correct me where I am going wrong ...Thanks! :D